# Consoling a close relative post-break-up

Tags: relationships

**The issue:**

A very close relative of mine just went through break up. After eight years together, his (ex-) girlfriend left him for a mutual friend of both of them.

Now there is quite a distance separating the two of us, so it would quite difficult for me to visit him (at least within the next few weeks).

Further, his birthday is approaching. I am going to be seeing him then and I would like to seize the opportunity to comfort him.

On another note, I would consider myself to be socially awkward which doesn't come as a help.

Finally, somewhat before that relationship had started, my relative went through a "mild" depression.

---

**The question:**

How could I help this relative going through this process?

I figured in such situations distraction and time are probably key. However, this is hardly answering my question.

---

**PS:** I tried to find similar questions pre-posting without success. Apologies if my questions comes as duplicate.

Comment: Have you ever "helped" your relative with something like that before? Do you know if he would be grateful for your help? Some people deal with things like these by (for some time) shutting down and distracting themselves, and don't want to be reminded on a family party by "nosy" relatives. I'm not saying this is how it will come across, but it might, so it would be interesting to know if your relative went through this before, and how you think he'd react. // (Specifically reacting to *I am going to be seeing him then and I would like to seize the opportunity to comfort him.*)

Comment: The last and only time he endured something similar, I was 15 or 16 years old. Together with several other members of the family, I believe to have helped him getting back on his feet. Besides, considering how close we are, I fancy me trying to help would be appreciated. But you absolutely have a point: maybe it is better - at least for a while - to let time heal the wound.

Comment: Why is there a distance? Why is it difficult for you to see him? I don't see the immediate relation to the break up. If you can explain this it surely would help to understand your question better.

Comment: @puck  Why do you think the distance and breakup are related?  I read that as "Please don't suggest that I spend a lot of time in his presence, as we are physically far away from each other.  I won't see him until his birthday."  So either things should be delayed until the birthday or proceed by phone/email or whatever distance friendly method.

Comment: @Brythan oh I read this as "now ... distance"="no more getting along with him, starting with the breakup" ... that was too much interpretation, sorry everybody! Then my question doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no real magic formula to helping someone cope through a hard time.  When I've gone through hard times, different friends have done different things.  What they have done has depended on their personality and my state at the time.  So there's no real "if A then B".

The first place to start is to be there for your relative.  I've found that starting out with a minimal agenda other than "be there for them" has been the most productive.  That allows flexibility and doesn't tie me to a specific path. The best thing that I ever experienced when breaking off a relationship was telling a friend, who immediately responded, "Wanna get a beer?"  That offer to spend time together meant more than anything anyone else could have said.

I'd start by seeing if he wants to do something he would normally enjoy.  If not, see what he wants to do.  He may be looking for exactly that - getting away from things that remind him of the relationship and a return to normalcy.  Or he may want to cry.  If that's the case, I'd let that happen as long as he doesn't descend into self-pity.

I've seen that people tend to go through a grieving process when relationships end.  There is sometimes denial (Maybe we can get back together), sadness (crying, etc), anger (that [fill in expletive here]), bargaining (if I just change, maybe we can restart) and finally acceptance.  You never really forget a long relationship and it takes time to deal with the sadness of no longer being in that relationship, but it happens.  I've seen it happen with divorced relatives as well as widowed grandmothers.

In the end, he and only he can navigate through this.  You can't change his feelings or perspective.  But what you can do is show him that others do care about him and that his life will continue on.  Empathize and listen.  That will be your best guide.

Some things to not do:

- Insult ex-girlfriend.  It comes across as fake and makes people question what you thought of her when she was around
- Say "There will be someone else"  Really?  Can you prove that?
- Say "It happens for a reason"  Sometimes things just happen
- Say "It wasn't meant to be"  So, the last 8 years were a waste?
- Encourage bad behavior.  You don't want to be the cause of something he'll regret in the rational light of day

Answer (score 2):

> How could I help this relative going through this process?

To help people move on from past troubles, the best you could do is help them get back to leading normal life. Constantly reminding them of the past troubles even with the good intentions of "comforting" will do more harm than good.

Make his birthday the best you can. Let him be happy again. Constantly reminding people that "I am here to fill the hole in your heart" doesn't fill it, but it can only help to dig it deeper. Holes in people's hearts are filled by doing good things to them.

Flowery language and philosophy aside, nothing good is going to come out of brooding over the past. This person probably wants to forget about the relationship and make a fresh start. Don't make it harder for them.